# for create operation, form data is used but in Tortoise ORM documentation they are using JSON, what is the best practice?

Tags: fastapi, tortoise-orm

I'm trying to make a Web App project using FastAPI and Tortoise ORM

I want to create a user(Registration) and mostly the data is Form data which is sent by the front-end and FastAPI docs does tells us how to handle Form data.

But the Example in Tortoise ORM docs (FastAPI Example) uses simple JSON data.

[image: create use example in Tortoise ORM]

**What is the best practice and what should I do?**

- link to Tortoise ORM and FastAPI example : https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/fastapi.html#main-py

*PS: Just one suggestion, Should I even use Tortoise ORM or switch to another ORM as Tortoise is still a young project (please also which other ORM I should consider)*

If I have written anything wrong please pardon me I'm new to web development.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use Form or JSON depends on which context your data is being submitted from. If it's submitted from a regular web form (i.e. `form` being submitted as a POST operation), it'll be form data. If you're using a frontend framework or designing an API to be used programmatically, it'll usually be easier and more expressive to use JSON. Neither is "better" (although plain form data can't express hierarchies as easily as JSON), but it depends on the context.

Tortoise ORM should be fine; it's popular. Other options is SQLAlchemy, orm, or possibly SQLModel - which is a new orm built on top of SQLAlchemy by the author of FastAPI - and designed for use with FastAPI.